# Fastest way to compute n-gram overlap matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, set, n-gram

I have a large corpus of documents that I want to merge if they have a notable n-gram overlap (in my case, I'm considering bigrams). Consider the list of sets:

```
corpus = [{'example', 'bigram'}, {'another', 'example'}, {'some', 'outlier'}]
```

I have the following code to compute the similarity matrix:

```
import numpy as np

sim_matrix = np.zeros((len(corpus), len(corpus)))
for i in range(len(corpus)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(corpus)):
        sim_matrix[i][j] = get_ngram_overlap(corpus[i], corpus[j])
        
np.fill_diagonal(sim_matrix, 1)
```

Where the `get_ngram_overlap` function is defined as follows:

```
def get_ngram_overlap(ngrams_s1, ngrams_s2):

    if min(len(ngrams_s1), len(ngrams_s2)) == 0:
        return 0

    common_ngrams = ngrams_s1 & ngrams_s2

    return len(common_ngrams)/min(len(ngrams_s1), len(ngrams_s2))
```

The result is a MxM matrix, where the M is the number of n-grams in my corpus

```
print(sim_matrix)
>> [[1.  0.5  0.]
   [0.  1.   0.]
   [0.  0.   1.]]
```

The problem is, when the M grows large, the code is really slow and this becomes really computationally expensive, because of the necessity to compare all unique pairs. **Are there ways to compute it more efficiently?** Like using an optimized distance matrix computation with a custom similarity metric that would work for sets of strings. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the computation faster to first build an index and run the `get_ngram_overlap()` only on combinations which have common words:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

# make the items in corpus frozensets (to make them hashable)
corpus = [frozenset({'example', 'bigram'}), frozenset({'another', 'example'}), frozenset({'some', 'outlier'})]

def get_ngram_overlap(ngrams_s1, ngrams_s2):
    mn = min(len(ngrams_s1), len(ngrams_s2))
    if mn == 0:
        return 0
    common_ngrams = ngrams_s1 & ngrams_s2
    return len(common_ngrams)/mn


index, nums = {}, {}
for i, b in enumerate(corpus):
    for word in b:
        index.setdefault(word, []).append(b)
    nums.setdefault(b, []).append(i)

index2 = {}
for k, v in index.items():
    for c in combinations(v, 2):
        index2[c] = get_ngram_overlap(*c)

sim_matrix = np.zeros((len(corpus), len(corpus)))

for a, b in index2:
    for x in nums[a]:
        for y in nums[b]:
            sim_matrix[(x, y) if x < y else (y, x)] = index2[(a, b)]

np.fill_diagonal(sim_matrix, 1)
print(sim_matrix)
```

Prints:

```
[[1.  0.5 0. ]
 [0.  1.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  1. ]]
```

---

A benchmark with 10k bigrams of 500 different words:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import combinations


random.seed(123)
corpus = [frozenset({f'word{random.randint(1, 500)}', f'word{random.randint(1, 500)}'}) for _ in range(10_000)]

def get_ngram_overlap(ngrams_s1, ngrams_s2):
    mn = min(len(ngrams_s1), len(ngrams_s2))
    if mn == 0:
        return 0
    common_ngrams = ngrams_s1 & ngrams_s2
    return len(common_ngrams)/mn


def fn1():
    sim_matrix = np.zeros((len(corpus), len(corpus)))
    for i in range(len(corpus)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(corpus)):
            sim_matrix[i][j] = get_ngram_overlap(corpus[i], corpus[j])

    np.fill_diagonal(sim_matrix, 1)
    return sim_matrix

def fn2():
    index, nums = {}, {}
    for i, b in enumerate(corpus):
        for word in b:
            index.setdefault(word, []).append(b)
        nums.setdefault(b, []).append(i)

    index2 = {}
    for k, v in index.items():
        for c in combinations(v, 2):
            index2[c] = get_ngram_overlap(*c)

    sim_matrix = np.zeros((len(corpus), len(corpus)))

    for a, b in index2:
        for x in nums[a]:
            for y in nums[b]:
                sim_matrix[(x, y) if x < y else (y, x)] = index2[(a, b)]

    np.fill_diagonal(sim_matrix, 1)
    return sim_matrix

assert np.array_equal(fn1(), fn2())

t1 = timeit(fn1, number=1)
t2 = timeit(fn2, number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my machine (Python 3.10/AMD Ryzen 5700x):

```
19.253960204077885
0.37714757514186203
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) (to get consecutive pairs of bigrams) and *triangular* computation ([`np.triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)) of an array:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_ngram_overlap(ngrams_s1, ngrams_s2):
    min_len = min(len(ngrams_s1), len(ngrams_s2))
    if min_len == 0:
        return 0
    return len(ngrams_s1 & ngrams_s2) / min_len

corpus = [{'example', 'bigram'}, {'another', 'example'}, {'some', 'outlier'}]
sim_matrix = np.zeros((len(corpus), len(corpus)))

# fill upper triangle with calculated overlaps 
sim_matrix[np.triu_indices(len(sim_matrix), 1)] = \
            list(get_ngram_overlap(*c) for c in combinations(corpus, 2))
np.fill_diagonal(sim_matrix, 1)
print(sim_matrix)
```

---

```
[[1.  0.5 0. ]
 [0.  1.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  1. ]]
```

Comment: That's a nice improvement, didn't know about the `triu_indices` function! I'm looking for a more optimized way however, as this is still kind of slow for large corpora..